# LibGdx MapProperties object method containsKey always returns false

Tags: java, libgdx

I am studying LibGdx framework, using Tiled map editor for creating and TiledMap class with TmxMapLoader() for reading .tmx data of the map, but MapProperties class's method containsKey failed in the if statement

I have tried save loading tmx file Tiled editor, it is interesting that i got 
MapObjects getCount() right.

```
TiledMap map;
//...
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/32/level0.tmx");
//...
MapLayer layer = map.getLayers().get(2);
   MapObjects objects = layer.getObjects();
   System.out.println(objects.getCount());  
// objects.getCount() returns 2 or 3 when i change items via editor
   MapObject  object = objects.get(0);
// Entity entity;  // omitted for testing 
   MapProperties prop = object.getProperties();
   if (prop.containsKey("type")){ 
       // ignored (always false) , i got 2 objects both with property
       // type 1 and type 2
       int i = prop.get("type", int.class);
       System.out.println(i);
    // entity = Entity.GetValue(i); // omitted for testing 
    // System.out.println(entity); // omitted for testing 
       // the goal is to store tile object types in Entity enum
   }
```

expected true inside if , but always false ,

EDIT: i added method description , maybe i misunderstood something
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapProperties.html#containsKey-java.lang.String-

Comment: i tested "typeZ" instead of "type" , still nothing

Comment: type != (type 1 || type 2)

Comment: @icarumbas you ever used Tiled Map Editor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tile Map Editor save **problem** (*embed tileset inside tmx file*) , java code was fine. 
A bit of info if anyone had problems with tileSets .

- Tile Map Editor's MAP file extension is *.tmx
- Tile Map Editor's tileSet file extension is *.tsx

Never save with embed tileset, you should keep seperate tmx and tsx files